# double[] = ToArray() from a CSV file

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, double

Im trying to import from a CSV file and two of my variables needs to be double arrays, its all being imported as a string and Im breaking it up by the ',' but I cannot convert from string to double[] and I cant find any info on how to do it... this is where Im at. Any help would be great.

```
public class CsvImporter
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Importing the Pay Records
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">The content of the csv file</param>param>
    /// <returns> Pay Records </returns>
    public static List<PayRecord> ImportPayRecords(string file)

    {
        var operations = new List<PayRecord>();
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(Path.GetFullPath($@"..\..\..\Import\{file}.csv")))
        {
            bool firstLine = true;
            for (string line = stream.ReadLine(); line != null; line = stream.ReadLine())
            {
                if (!firstLine)
                {
                    operations.Add(createPayRecord(line));
                }
                else
                {
                    firstLine = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return operations;
    }

    private static PayRecord createPayRecord(string line)
    {
        string[] columns = line.Split(',');
        int id = int.Parse(columns[0]);
        double[] hours = columns[1].ToArray();
        double[] rates = columns[2].ToArray();
        int visa = int.Parse(columns[3]);
        int yearToDate = int.Parse(columns[4]);


        switch (visa)
        {
            case 417:
                return new WorkingHolidayPayRecord(id, hours, rates, visa, yearToDate);
            case 462:
                return new WorkingHolidayPayRecord(id, hours, rates, visa, yearToDate);
            default:
                return new ResidentPayRecord(id, hours, rates);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: We need to see a sample of what the actual file looks like.

Comment: `columns[1]` and `columns[2]` are just strings. When you call `ToArray()`, you get an array of characters and I don't know how you could expect anything else.

Comment: `its all being imported as a string` of course it is - a CSV file is just a *text file* of comma separated values

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Select()` to apply a transformation to the results of the `.Split()` operation.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = ParseCSV(@"1,2,3,4,5");
        // {1,2,3,4,5}
    }

    public static double[] ParseCSV(this string row)
    {
        var parts = row.Split(',');
        return parts.Select((item) => double.Parse(item)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

<sub>Requires `System.Linq`</sub>